# Excel won't recognize sheet pattern

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2013

I have some rows and the formula is pretty simple:

```
='01'.B2
='02'.B2
='03'.B2
```

If I select all three rows and try to autofill, it doesn't follow the sequence of the sheets.

It will go like:

```
='01'.B2
='02'.B2
='03'.B2
='01'.B4
='02'.B4
='03'.B4
```

How can I work around this?

Comment: what is the meaning of the formula you have? It doesn't seem to be a valid formula. Please note that Excel don't recognize non-valid formulas.

Comment: It works. It takes the value of the cell B2 from the sheet 01, 02, 03.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `INDIRECT()` as a workaround:

`=INDIRECT("'"&TEXT(ROW(A1),"00")&"'.B2")`